# Can I pre-emptively secure PS Plus free games, without yet owning a Playstation Console?

Tags: ps4

I would like to get The Binding of Isaac for with this months PS Plus membership. However, I don't plan to purchase a ps4 until March. Could I buy a PS Plus membership, go to the playstation store website, and secure my purchase of the free game without actually owning a Sony console yet?

Comment: Unfortunately I already own every PS Plus eligible console (PS Vita, PS3 & PS4) so I can't test it, but you'll probably need to go to the [browser version of the SEN store](https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com) to do this. If anyone with a PS Plus subscription can verify this, I'd like to know as well (out of pure curiosity). Also, feel free to use the link I provided in your own answer.

Comment: I don't have PSPlus but @Nolonar 's theory should work, if the Browser Version of the store allows you to buy the game then when you get the PS4 you should be able to go onto into your transaction history and re-download it in the same way as you would had you brought it on the PS4 and then got a new PS4 and wanted to re-download the game

Comment: A years PS Plus subscription is about $5 per month, so it'll cost you $15 or so to subscribe until March just so you can get The Bind of Isaac: Rebirth "free". For $15 you can just buy the game in March and not have to worry about whether it will work or not. You could also spend $15 to get the PC/Mac version and start playing now.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that this worked for me on the Vita before I bought it.

I bought my Vita last year, in March, and was able to go to my download list and download PS+ titles for Vita that I had associated with my account the previous fall.

It should work the same way for the PS4.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'm pretty sure you can. I can confirm that this worked for my PS3 and PS Vita, I created subscription before I bought them. I would assume that whis works same way for PS4. Actually it works, I can do purchases of a PS+ PS4 games, and they are in my download list, it's just that I can't be 100% sure yet (but I'm 99.97% sure ^_^).

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do this for various PS4 games on the PSPlus service, and they appear on my downloads list.

The option is available to download Pix the Cat or Dust: An Elysium Tale despite them not currently being available on PS+ or previously downloaded. I did not have a PS4 at the time of "purchase".

I have also done this with my PS Vita, as I ended up without a Vita for a few months. I have successfully downloaded games that I got on PS+ and had expired since.

Answer (score -5):

Unfortunately no, you can't. I discovered this when I used to download every single "free" psplus game and pause the download until I wanted it, in the hope it would stay there forever. If you haven't downloaded the game fully onto your playstation before it gets removed from psplus games list, you can't download it.

sorry!

---

### Edit

By the way, as some people have recently downvoted this answer... the PS Plus scheme has changed drastically since I originally posted this. You can now just press "add to library". so this answer is now irrelevant.

Comment: I don't think this is true. I can't say for sure about the PS4, but I don't own a Vita, yet I can claim Vita games and once they are claimed (they do not have to be downloaded) they remain in my download list and can be downloaded at any time later, as long as the PS Plus subscription is active. Either way, it can not matter whether you fully download the games, as they run on a subscription basis. If you have a PS Plus game installed and the subscription runs out, you won't be able to start it anymore anyways.

Comment: I've just had a look and I have quite a few Vita games I got as free PS Plus games available for download in my download list. You can download all games you have previously accumulated from the list. The amount of games adds up the longer your subscription runs.

Comment: *"If you haven't downloaded the game fully onto your playstation before it gets removed from psplus games list, you can't download it."* if PS+ Games are removed after the deal is over then they would have to be removed from your *Transaction History* forcing you to re-buy it if you need to get a new console and want to re-download your games, in that case then what's the point of the offer then?

Comment: you guys have obviously never actually tried because that's exactly what I thought. I promise you: if you don't fully download a game or run it before it has gone from the current selection then you cannot use it. the game will still show but you will not be able to run it. obviously if you have actually downloaded it and played it before it gets removed then you get to keep it for the length of your subscription. If there is not anyone who can prove me wrong then I see no reason for getting 4 down votes... I've tried this before. I know what happens.

Comment: @Panomosh. I went and downloaded Hotline Miami on my PS Vita. I got the game from PS Plus, but never got around to downloading and playing it. The game has been removed from PS Plus in April and it is downloading just fine right now. Are you sure your subscription didn't simply run out when you tried to download them? For the record: games you've received for free through PS Plus are only available as long as you have a valid PS Plus subscription.

Comment: @Panomosh I haven't tried it with Vita of course since I don't have one, but I just recently downloaded PES 2014 from PS Plus from a few months ago, and I hadn't downloaded it before, I only claimed it for later. It works. The official Playstation Blog also notes each month about the games leaving the collection: "Don’t miss out! Make sure to add any of the games scheduled to leave the service to your download list now to ensure you get to play them!" http://blog.eu.playstation.com/2014/11/04/playstation-plus-november-content-update-little-something-extra/

Comment: Nolonar let me know if it runs when you download it! I've got 2 games on my xmb that I can't play because what I thought to be this issue (bioshock, virtua fighter) it just says "content expired" and I had figured that was because in order to "activate" the game, you need to start it up at least one. I hope they have changed it, that would be awesome.

Comment: @Panomosh That should be the message you get when you try to start a plus game while you don't have an active subscription. However, once the subscription is renewed all games can be played again. I tried this with Burnout Paradise when Sony gave away a month of plus and the game for the hacking incident in 2010. When the month expired I couldn't start it anymore, now I can download and play it. If you have an active subscription it should work with your games too.

Comment: You can check the licence and when it expores by pressing triangle on the game in the xmb on Ps3. With a subscription it always changes the date according to the expiration of the subscription to plus.

Comment: I have had an active subscription for the last 2 years Kodama

Comment: @Panomosh That's weird, maybe there was actually a change made at some point, but I thought it always was like it is now. I've only had Plus for 9 months so I don't know. But at this point it is definitely enough to just add it to the download list. I had to install a new hard drive to have enough space to download some PS Plus games and just claimed them to do it later, and it worked. What does the expiration date say on the games that don't work (like Bioshock)? It should be visible with triangle->Information (or something like that).

Comment: This is something that can happen when a game has a Full Game Trial. If you activated a trial while the game wasn't free on PSPlus and you aren't done with it, you have to finish the trial and get the free purchase before the month ends. This happened to me for Far Cry 2, I had started the trial months before it went free but only played half an hour. After the free month ended I finished the trial and it showed as not purchased so I didn't get it for free. So the tip you want to give is: if a game has the trial active you have to finish it before purchase, free or not free.

Comment: By the way, the PS Plus scheme has changed drastically since I originally posted this. You can now just press "add to library". so this answer is now irrelevant.